# how to resolve this using min and max functions but no conditional statements

Tags: python, max, min

```
def clip(lo, x, hi):
    '''
    Takes in three numbers and returns a value based on the value of x.
    Returns:
     - lo, when x < lo
     - hi, when x > hi
     - x, otherwise
    '''
```

Comment: I feel like the dirty trick where you use // as a conditional might apply here.

Comment: Oh wait, no, this is easy `max(lo, min(x,hi))`

Comment: This question assumes that `lo < hi` right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `x = max(low, x)` to get the bigger one out of the two; if `x` is smaller than `low`, `max()` will return `low`. Else it'll return `x`.

Now that you got the bigger one out of the two, you need to use `x = min(high, x)` to get the smaller one out of the new `x` and `high`.

When combined, you get:

```
def clip(low, x, high):  # Why not use full names?
    x = max(low, x)
    x = min(high, x)
    return x
```

Which can be further shortened to:

```
def clip(low, x, high):
    return min(high, max(low, x))
```